# TYPO3 v9 admin panel without css styles and js

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a problem with one of the TYPO3 installations on my server. The whole thing loads but without styles and js. Comparing the neighboring installation on the same server (which works properly), the difference appears in the file paths.

The correct path has a form: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/typo3/sysext/backend/Resources/Public/Css/backend.css?1571297500" media="all">`

In an installation where the whole installation does not work, the path has a form: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/typo3temp/assets/compressed/backend-0ec6c1600f439ab982e3d6ab38b2463c.css.1574420118.gzip" media="all">`

There is no such file in the specified location - only

- `backend-0ec6c1600f439ab982e3d6ab38b2463c.css`
- `backend-0ec6c1600f439ab982e3d6ab38b2463c.css.gzip`

If I remove the fragment `1574420118.gzip` from the code, part of the styles is loaded.

The strange thing is that both installations have the same `.htaccess` file and still generate different code.

Any idea where the reason for this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is an installation-wide setting called `versionNumberInFilename`.

It appears you have this enabled in the broken install, but not in the working one.

You can change the setting under 'Admin Tools -> Settings'. If you can't get there, you can change it in your `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` or `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php` file.

[image]

Comment: I have this option disabled but stilll no styles

Comment: @anyapps Can you see any errors in the console? Can you see if the resources are loaded? Is mod_rewrite enabled and working on the server?